# Idiomatic way of assigning parameter or default value

Tags: ruby

There has got to be a better way of assigning a default value if `params[:value]` is nil.  Now I'm doing this:

```
if !params[:equity].nil?
   equity = params[:equity]
else
   equity = 0.00
end
```

Isn't there a way of doing something like this:

```
equity = params[:equity].nil? ? 0.00 : params[:equity]
```

I tried Hash methods like `replace`, `select`, or `merge`, but they don't really work as I need.

Comment: just a sidenote - `if !` is same as `unless`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the short-circuit OR operator `||` like so:

```
value = param || 0.00 # where param is something like params[key]
```

If you want to ignore blank values (like empty strings), you can add the presence method, like so:

```
value = param.presence || 0.00
```

If the param value can be Numeric (Float / Integer), nil, or empty string, you can shorten the command like so:

```
value = param.to_f # will return 0.0 when param is nil or empty string
```

Comment: Thank you.  I can't believe I didn't try this before, I must've had ||= plus I had a mess of code everywhere :\  Interesting side effect of the to_f too.

Answer (score 4):

You can always do:

```
equity = params[:equity].presence || 0.00
```

The [`presence`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence) method is part of ActiveSupport, and works like this:

> Returns the receiver if it’s present otherwise returns nil.

The logical or (`||`) operator, when used in assignment, assigns the first value that is not falsey.

Comment: nice to know about `presence`, +1. I used to using `present?`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on assignment too.

Answer (score 1):

This is very common in Ruby:

```
equity = params[:equity] || 0.00
```

It will assign `0.00` to `equity` when `params[:equity]` is `nil` or `false`.

If you want to assign `0.00` to `equity` only when `params[:equity]` is `nil` (not `false`), and you're using Rails, `presence` as mentioned by Drenmi is a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a default value to [`Hash#fetch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch):

```
equity = params.fetch(:equity, 0.0) #=> 0.0
```